# How do I prevent the inclusion of periods when double-clicking to select text in a Flex 4 TextArea?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, text, selection, editing

How do I prevent the inclusion of periods when double-clicking to select text in a Flex 4 TextArea?

For example, in a Flex 4 TextArea component, if I have the words "something.else" and I double-click on the word "something", it highlights "something.else".

How do I make it only highlight "something"?

I've googled the heck out of this, dug through the API, examined the related classes and haven't found anything "official".

NOTE: I would prefer to avoid simply intercepting the double-click event to handle setting the selection range myself as the complexity of restoring the other existing functionality may become insurmountable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)
TextArea uses RichEditableText.
RichEditableText uses SelectionManager.
SelectionManager has public function mouseDoubleClickHandler. 
mouseDoubleClickHandler uses ParagraphElement(which is final class) and its findPreviousWordBoundary and findNextWordBoundary functions.
And they use TextBlock's functions with similar names. And TextBlock is a part of playerglobal.swc.

So, the only 'professional' way with overrideing methods can be applied by overriding SelectionManager's handler, and then extending RichEditableText and some infrastructure classes to make it use of your custom SelectionManager.

But it's not an easy way.

2)You can place one of the space characters around '.' (preferring narrow ones or creating custom font where one of those characters has 0 width).

```
rslt[0x0020] =  true;  //SPACE
            rslt[0x1680] =  true;  //OGHAM SPACE MARK
            rslt[0x180E] =  true;  //MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR
            rslt[0x2000] =  true;  //EN QUAD
            rslt[0x2001] =  true;  //EM QUAD
            rslt[0x2002] =  true;  //EN SPACE
            rslt[0x2003] =  true;  //EM SPACE
            rslt[0x2004] =  true;  //THREE-PER-EM SPACE
            rslt[0x2005] =  true;  //FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
            rslt[0x2006] =  true;  //SIZE-PER-EM SPACE
            rslt[0x2007] =  true;  //FIGURE SPACE
            rslt[0x2008] =  true;  //PUNCTUATION SPACE
            rslt[0x2009] =  true;  //THIN SPACE
            rslt[0x200A] =  true;  //HAIR SPACE
            rslt[0x202F] =  true;  //NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
            rslt[0x205F] =  true;  //MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
            rslt[0x3000] =  true;  //IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
            //members of LineSeparator category
            rslt[0x2028] =  true;  //LINE SEPARATOR
            //members of ParagraphSeparator category
            rslt[0x2029] =  true;
            //Other characters considered to be a space
            rslt[0x0009] =  true; //CHARACTER TABULATION
            rslt[0x000A] =  true; //LINE FEED
            rslt[0x000B] =  true; //LINE TABULATION
            rslt[0x000C] =  true; //FORM FEED
            rslt[0x000D] =  true; //CARRIAGE RETURN
            rslt[0x0085] =  true; //NEXT LINE
            rslt[0x00A0] =  true; //NO-BREAK SPACE
```

3) So, I think that your option with custom doubleclick handler is no so bad.

Comment: Holy crap that was informative. This gives me a lot to think about, thank you for being so thorough here :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I went with:

```
protected var lastClickedSelectionAnchorIndex:int = 0;

protected function textArea_doubleClickHandler( event:MouseEvent ):void
{

    if( event.target != textArea.textDisplay ) return;

    if( textArea.selectionAnchorPosition == textArea.selectionActivePosition ) return;

    var targetText:String = textArea.text;

    if( targetText == null || targetText == "" || targetText.indexOf( "." ) === -1 ) return;

    var selectedText:String = targetText.substring( textArea.selectionAnchorPosition, textArea.selectionActivePosition );

    if( selectedText == null || selectedText == "" || selectedText.indexOf( "." ) === -1 ) return;

    var selectionStart:int = textArea.selectionAnchorPosition;
    var selectionEnd:int = textArea.selectionActivePosition;

    if( selectionStart > selectionEnd ){

        selectionStart = textArea.selectionActivePosition;
        selectionEnd = textArea.selectionAnchorPosition;

    }

    if( lastClickedSelectionAnchorIndex < selectionStart || lastClickedSelectionAnchorIndex > selectionEnd ){

        return;

    }

    var newSelectionStart:int = targetText.lastIndexOf( ".", lastClickedSelectionAnchorIndex );
    var newSelectionEnd:int = targetText.indexOf( ".", lastClickedSelectionAnchorIndex );

    var startSelectionOffset:int = 1;

    if( newSelectionStart < selectionStart || newSelectionStart === -1 ){

        newSelectionStart = selectionStart;

        startSelectionOffset = 0;

    }

    if( newSelectionEnd > selectionEnd || newSelectionEnd === -1 ){

        newSelectionEnd = selectionEnd;

    }

    textArea.selectRange( newSelectionStart + startSelectionOffset, newSelectionEnd );

}

protected function textArea_mouseDownHandler( event:MouseEvent ):void
{

    try{

        lastClickedSelectionAnchorIndex = textArea.selectionAnchorPosition;

    }catch( error:Error ){

        lastClickedSelectionAnchorIndex = 0;

    }

}
```